# How to create a toolbar in a TableView with a Label?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I would like to add a toolbar with a label entitled "Save your search?" on the left and a button "Save" on the right that triggers a specific action when tapped. How could I do that programmatically, especially I want this Toolbar to show up only when a particular View is loaded on a screen but not on every view.

Also, I want the toolbar to have a static image as background. "Save" button will also have a static image for background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to check; why do you need to add this toolbar of sorts onto a TableView? Depending on how you've set things up; and specially seeing that you need to conditionally hide/show this toolbar, might be easier to add it outside the tableView (just above it I guess).

Seeing as you need to hide/show this toolbar at will; guess you can simply use a UIView for it and add the UIButtons on top as subviews; --> declare it as a property in the .h file so that it can be freely accessed in the .m file whenever you need to hide / show it.

Did you need help on some specific issue related to this perhaps; or would this serve as a goo enough starting point?

Comment: Do you mean whether to display the toolbar separate from the UITableView? Its not a big deal either way. If you want to have it bundled with the UITableView, you can assign the toolbar view as the 'tableHeaderView' for that table; and this will be shown above the table.